# Select tab from UITabBarController programmatically and load view

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am having an issue loading the view of selected tab item.

I am using the code below in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController` at item 1 of the `UITabBar`.

```
UITabBarController *tab = self.tabBarController;

if (tab){
   NSLog(@"I have a tab bar");
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
   [self.tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay];
   self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;
} else {
    NSLog(@"I don't have");
}
```

When I press Back To Tab Controller Button, it selects the tab but it doesn't open the required view. It shows the view of the tab at index 0.

[image]

Comment: Why are you changing tabs in `viewDidLoad`? Also `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:]` and `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: I had tried Both the things one by one.Both didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your code in viewDidAppear: method instead of view did load.
it will work..